# Shuould we perform LINQ directly in asp net mvc views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

Looking through the project we are working on (ASP MVC 3.0), I have seen this part of code in one of my ASPX views:

```
var groups = Model.GroupBy(t => new { t.OrganizationUnitName, t.OrganizationUnitId,   t.ServiceTermDate }).OrderBy(m =>m.Key.ServiceTermDate).ThenBy(m => m.Key. OrganizationUnitId);
  foreach (var group in groups){
             var data = group.Select(t => new 
                                   {
                                       t.PersonFullName, 
                                       t.ServiceTermStatusName,
                                       t.VisitTypeName,
                                       SubType = ControllerHelper.LocalizedPersonSubType(t.PersonSubTypeName),
                                       t.MedicalServiceName,
                                       t.PersonId,
                                       t.ServiceTermId,
                                       t.Phone,
                                       CountryName = t.Name,
                                       PersonUniqueNumber = t.GetUniqueIdentifyingNumber(),

                                   }).OrderBy(m => m.HoursFromMinutesFrom);

foreach(var item in data){%>
...............
//render table and table rows, for sample
    <tr>
        <td><%= item.PersonFullName%></td>
    </tr>
..............  
<%}%>
<%}%>               




<%}%>
```

I am not sure this is best coding practice, shouldn't LINQ statement be placed in controller helper (or somewhere else) instead in view directly? And if I'm right, how that could be done utilizing best coding practices?

Thank you in advance

It seems that  LINQ which is performed directly in the view is not only at the wrong place but also it raise another interesting question: if we place it into service layer or controller or controller helper, then how it would be passed in this case - anonymous type         IGrouping     to strongly typed view?

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I wouldn't use LINQ in the view. Do this in the controller for unit testing purposes.

If there is logic being performed, in a larger application I'd even move it out to a services assembly which would contain all of your LINQ queries.

Your view should be as basic as possible. Any ordering, grouping or sorting should be done in your controller (preferably with the help of a helper method which is re-usable for different actions across the application).

Answer (score 0):

The philosophy of ASP.NET MVC (and I'd say of the MVC paradigm in general) is:

- Put as little code as possible in the view. Ideally, you should just
  reference data in the model class, perhaps with some loops or
  conditional statements.
- Do not put complex application logic in the controller methods.
  Ideally, these methods should just collect the input data from the user
  (if any), perform all the appropriate security and data validations, then pass the data to an application logic (or business logic)
  class, then redirect to the appropriate view with the new model data
  obtained from the logic class. (I once read that a controller method should have no more than 10 lines of code; maybe this is a bit exagerated but you get the point)

So I would say: not only the view should be LINQ free; the controller should be like this too.

Comment: yes, a service class should contain all your linq logic and this called via the controller action. keeps the controller actions easily BELOW 10 lines of code in most cases :)

Answer (score 0):

> **Yes you can do it on View** but i prefer to use Business logic work done through
>   controller rather than on View.

View is just used to display the GUI that must be as basic and simple to reduce the complexity of the GUI.

To make application code consistent, maintainable and reusable put these type of logic on Business Logic Classes except writing on Controller or view.

Answer (score 0):

MVC is about abstraction of concerns.

The code you have posted above is breaking the most important rule of MVC. The view is the view, it has no business logic or data access code. It simply displays data that it is given to it in a nice way that can allow for presentation and user interaction. Think of the view as something you could give to a designer who knows nothing of asp.net.

The problem you have above is a perfect candidate for a ViewModel. The "Model" variable that is being used here is wrong, since you are taking it and then changing it to display something different. If the domain model doesn't fit then the controller should create a ViewModel that looks exactly as the view expects. There are a few ways of doing this. But one way is for example:

```
public ActionResult DoSomething()
{
    List<DomainModel> modelCollection = getListOfDomainModels();
    // Perform ViewModel projection
    var viewModelList = modelCollection
       .GroupBy(t => new { t.OrganizationUnitName, t.OrganizationUnitId,   t.ServiceTermDate })
       .OrderBy(m =>m.Key.ServiceTermDate)
       .ThenBy(m => m.Key. OrganizationUnitId)
       .Select(p => new MyViewModel()
        {
             FullName = t.PersonFullName, 
             StatusName = t.ServiceTermStatusName,
             // etc ...
        });
    return View("DoSomethingView", viewModelList);
}
```

Now your Model variable will contain the correct model for the view.

Depending on your project's size and requirements you can make this alot better by performing the whole query in another layer outside of the controller and then projecting to a ViewModel inside your controller.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be doing it in either the View or the Controller.  Thus without giving you to much to chew at a a time you will want to have Separation of concerns (SOC) and keep it DRY (Don't repeat yourself) otherwise it becomes a maintenance nightmare.

If you put that code in the view (which is the worst place for it).  1. What happens if you want to use same or similar code elsewhere?  2. How will you step through debugging your code in this manner?

This is the equivalent of placing sql queries in a ASP.NET webforms  .aspx file, not even in the code behind .aspx.cs file.  Not using your model or a repository pattern and putting the code in the controller is another bad idea as a controller ActionResult has a Single Responsibility (SRP) of handling request, by smothering it with this code you have introduced an anti-pattern.  Keep the code clean in organized areas.  Don't be afraid to add class library projects.  Look up the Repository pattern and eventually get to the point of doing unit testing and using DI (Dependency Injection) not just for unit test, but for a loosely coupled / highly cohesive application.